# Kafka confgiuration with ssl with bitnami image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, bitnami-kafka

Hello everyone while trying to set up kafka with ssl certs with bitnami image i m getting following error `No available authentication scheme for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.`.

I have used self signed certficates for authentication.I am attaching my docker-compose.yml for reference.

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: SSL://:9093
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes 
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SSL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_PROTOCOL: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: kafkakeystorepass
      KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: kafkatruststorepass
    volumes:
      - "./secrets/kafka.broker.keystore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks"
      - "./secrets/kafka.broker.truststore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks"
```